# Python packages for iterating files in limited sibling subdirectories?

Tags: python, wildcard, glob, ls

Supposing we have a folder structure like the below:

```
root/a/1.txt
root/a/2.txt
root/a/3.json
root/b/1.txt
root/b/2.txt
root/b/3.json
root/c/1.txt
root/c/2.txt
```

And I wanna iterate files in some special subdirectories(not all). For example, get all `.txt` files in subdirectories `a` and `b`.

Of course, we can easily achieve it with `for` loop and `os.listdir()/glob.glob()` in python. But I am looking for a python package (if exists) that behave as simple as `unix shell ls`.

```sh
ls ./root/{a,b}/*.txt

# output:
# root/a/1.txt
# root/a/2.txt
# root/b/1.txt
# root/b/2.txt
```

Does anyone know such a python package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically you can use glob for that example as `a` and `b` are single characters.

```
>>> glob.glob('./root/[ab]/*.txt')
['./root/a/1.txt', './root/a/2.txt', './root/b/1.txt', './root/b/2.txt']
```

Otherwise you'd need multiple glob calls (which you could make a function for)

```
glob('./root/dir1/*.txt') + glob('./root/dir1/*.txt')
```

However you're asking about `{a,b}` which is *"shell brace expansion"* and not part of the glob syntax.

See https://pypi.org/project/wcmatch/ for that and more.

Comment: Hmm..., The two code snippets you gave are similar to the method I described in the question. But `wcmatch`  is exactly what I want, thx!

Answer (score 0):

As @Karl Thornton mentioned above, package `wcmatch` fully meets the needs.

Just give more details here.

```
# pip install wcmatch
>>> from wcmatch import glob as wcglob
>>> wcglob.glob('./root/{a,b}/*.txt', flags=wcglob.BRACE)
```

`wcmatch` enables Bash style brace expansion for `glob` with flags `BRACE`